# Methodology for naturally occurring portals

Tags: teleportation

What methodology would portals have created within a world to a seemingly random other part of the world if they are natural occurrences and therefore do not use technology?

The world is a simple world without technology (think Lord of the Rings).

So portal occurrences for example...

One is found in a cave in a land South of the equator yet the traveller appears in a forest in a land North of the equator.

How did it appear?
Are they as old as the world or are they living in some way, i.e. they are born / created, develop / grow and die / disappear?
Is there a method / reason for how two portals connect in very different locations?

Comment: They have technology. You remember Minas Tirith? I would like to see someone build that 'without technology' :) This question has a....confusing wording. What are you asking? How are the two portals connected? Do you want a [tag:science-based] answer or a [tag:magic] based answer? If the latter, then what are the rules and parameters of your magic?

Comment: a naturally occurring portal like a wormhole ? If so, maybe you could consider moving the question to Physic SE?

Answer (score 2):

**How did it appear?** 
You could make it mystic based magic. Make it uncontrollable. It could be attracted by massive sacrifice, prays, a death of someone significant, or other events. Noone knows why magic decided if someone was important or not, it just happened. Before anyone thought to examine it, most of magic was already used. People usually picked caves, forests for their templates so it will explain why portals formed there.

**Is there a method / reason for how two portals connect in very different locations?** Magic power would concentrate in those places, and randomly connect to places with same density of power in another place. It might require both spots to be created at the same time, to create link. This way you could have alot of portals without exit, entering such portal will cause anihilation of adventurer.

**Grow and die.** With time, magic could spread, lowering the stability of portal, at some point, loosing the link with original exit. It might change it's destination to another portal without exit, with similar density or it might turn into a trap. Decay process might be speed up by usage, so group of travelers entering unstable portal might end up in different places of world. Some of them might even die.

**World getting older.** In the beggining there was alot of roaming magic, so portals were created all the time. With time, most of it was concentrated into existing portals. This means, there is little to no unused magic to create new portals, making people believe that gods left them. Rarely new portal would appear if old one dissolved somewhere near.